# Toggle elements that user has highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call `.toggle()` on elements that user has highlighted?

For example:

[image]

Comment: -stares- -blinks- -stares again- Nope, I don't get it...

Comment: click and shift click, click and drag?

Comment: What do mean when you say you want to toggle elements?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: It's not easy, but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse?rq=1

Comment: @Diodeus it's a bit different...

Comment: It is, but it demonstrates element selection well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `getSelection()` for get the itens selected.

Comment: Select some text in your browser and run this function on the console, you will see that the elements appear you selected. Why would you evaluate me negatively? Or at least tried to run the search function?